# HorizontalScrollView не занимает весь экран

Tags: android

У меня есть таблица, которую я хочу прокручивать при помощи HorizontalScrollView, но когда я вставляю этот элемент, то всё ломается.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="*">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_span="6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Weather Table"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView00"
        android:text="" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Feb 7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Feb 8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:text="Feb 9"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="Feb 10"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView05"
        android:text="Feb 11"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:text="Day High"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="28°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="26°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="23°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="17°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="19°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="20°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="20°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView110"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="20°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView111"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="20°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView112"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="20°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:text="Day Low"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="15°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="14°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="3°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="5°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="6°F"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:clickable="true">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView30"
        android:text="Conditions"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>


</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image: Скрин экрана]

Comment: как бы логично, что он занимает не весь экран, если вы ему сказали занимать не мвесь экран... `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте для `HorizontalScrollView` ширину задать так:

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: Эффект тот же(.

Comment: @GiorgiGusakov а этот слой корневой? Покажите разметку `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для HorizontalScrollView задать так:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Если нет, то и в `TableLayout` указать `"fill_parent"`

Comment: Пробовал и так и так. Картинка такая же.